# Specified method is not supported when using Count() in Linq with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

When I am using `.Count()` I am getting this error:

> the specified method not supported

At this line am getting error like `Sql not found`:

```
session.Query<Table>().Select(x => new { x.Id }).Distinct();
```

This is the full code:

```
var List = session.Query<Table>().Select(x => new { x.Id }).Distinct();
foreach (var id in SelectedIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    var count = List.Where(x => x.Id == Int32.Parse(id)).Count();
    if (count > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Is it problem with Nhibernate or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put out the cast like this:

```
int idCompare = Int32.Parse(id);
var count = List.Where(x => x.Id == idCompare).Count();
```

Linq is not able to convert every .NET Framework advanced function to sql.

Maybe this solves your issue.

When you need to check whether a .NET method is available in linq you might want to check [this source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456828(v=vs.100).aspx) and also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/clr-method-to-canonical-function-mapping)

Comment: I have tried converting it into List even though I am getting same error at this line, 
           var count = List.Where(x => x.Id == idCompare).Count();

Comment: Could you show the exact error with stacktrace or full error description?